# How to add an event to an element just created?

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-events

How can I add an event (by Mootools) to an element just created via `set("html")`, and inserted through the DOM?

```
$(document).addEvent("domready", function(){
      $(someel).set("html", "<p class='someclass'></p>");
      $$("someclass").somefn("click", function(){...});//somefn: that add the "click" event to the <p> element

});
```

Comment: you can use delegated events which get added to `someel` and match any childnoes you add later. see http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Delegation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So. via event delegation, adding a single event to top most element:

```
document.addEvent("domready", function(){
    $('foo').addEvents({
        'click:relay(p.someclass)': function(){
            alert('very well');
        }
    }).set("html", "<p class='someclass'>click me</p>");
});
```

or chaining it like so, adding events to all elements directly:

```
document.addEvent("domready", function(){
    $('foo').set("html", "<p class='someclass'>click me</p>")
        .getElements('.someclass').addEvent('click', function(){
            alert('chained');
        });
});
```

method 1 is more performant and allows for adding/removal or matching elements without rebinding.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [**Element constructor**](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3aconstructor). A code example could be like this:

```
$(document).addEvent("domready", function () {
    var pElement = new Element('p', {           // create a new element
        'class': 'someclass',                     // give it a class
        'html': 'Click me to make me alive...'  // give it some HTML
    });

    $('someel').adopt(pElement);                // have someone adopt it
    pElement.addEvent("click", function () {    // add event to it here OR in the Element constructor
        alert('Hello world!'); 
    });
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xyFqK/)

Comment: don't use `class` on its own, its a [reserved identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699851%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) and will throw in IE if it's not in quotes. also, mootools supports an events object that can be passed to the constructor - http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/uND48/

Comment: @DimitarChristoff, very true, good point. I think its worth having your answer also, I like the zen style on your fiddle. Will be the first to vote it up :)

Comment: Sergio, I meant without class constructor, just adding it via set("html", "come tag/element");

Comment: @Donovant, I will check this later, am in the middle of deadline. Check Dimitar's suggestion.